# How can I build with an iOS 6 SDK in Xcode 9?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have the SDK and put it in Xcode's sdk directory (for the simulator and the project directory) but I don't know how to change the base sdk from latest iOS to the sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the base SDK to an earlier system. And it would be useless even if you could; the App Store will not accept an app built against anything earlier than iOS 11.

You might want your app to *run* on an earlier system; in that case, what you would change is the *deployment target*.

(But I don't know whether you would be able to get your app to run on a system that early; the earliest officially supported deployment target is iOS 8, and I would not suggest trying to go earlier, even if you can hack your way around the restriction. There are too many gross incompatibilities.)

Comment: I didn't intend to publish the app to the app store, but I guess your answer is correct.

Comment: Well, what's the goal? If the idea is just to write an app for yourself that will be iOS 6-native, you will need a really old version of Xcode (and an old Mac system to run it on). Perhaps it would be possible to help more if we knew what you are really trying to do.

Comment: i want to see what I could do with an iOS 6 interface since I am more familiar with a modern one. And it's just a test app to see if I could still load apps to my 3gs. What version of Xcode do I need?